# Solr : No results returned when using *

Tags: solr

I'm working on a solr query similar to the following:
(key:value*).

When running this, there are two cases :

- if "value" is a big word, then no results are returned. But when I remove the "*", I get results.
- If value is a small word then results are returned.

Any idea about what can be the reason of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a wildcard, [most of the analysis chain isn't invoked](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultitermQueryAnalysis). So if you have a field that is tokenized, lowercased and then processed in another way (i.e. using a stemming filter usually), the analysis chain doesn't happen as you'd expect it to.

Since you're observing this with longer words, it matches neatly with stemming being applied when you're indexing, but not when you're using a wildcard (since that wouldn't make sense - when the whole token isn't present, stemming the text would give very weird results).

You can use a non-stemmed text field [that only have MultiTermAware filters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultitermQueryAnalysis) (usually the only thing useful is the LowercaseFilter for most configurations).

Wut when you're using a wildcard, the wildcard can evaluate to multiple tokens/terms (i.e. which is what multiterm refers to). Since this doesn't make sense for many filters, they're not invoked when a wildcard is present - such as the stemming filter. But when you're *indexing* content, there is no wildcard present, and each filter is invoked.

What happens is that stemming takes place when you're indexing your content, but not when you're searching. Indexing `windows` might get turned into `window`, but `windows*` tries to find any term/token that starts with the actual value `windows` - but since `windows` got turned into `window` - there is none that matches, even if the prefix was the same as the text when indexing.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for your answer. The issue that I have is about one long word, so there is no tokenizing I guess.

Comment: That just means that it's a single token, and still that the analysis chain doesn't run as you expect it to.

Comment: so it is like the analysis chain consider the word as multi term word ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more detailed explanation about what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I see what can be the reason. I'll try to implement the solution.

Comment: I could resolve the issue by removing the filter PorterStemFilterFactory or replacing it by EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory. I know that PorterStemFilterFactory is an aggressive stemmer. Could you please give me more details about this and tell me if there is an other solution. Thanks :)

Comment: It will still give you the same problems in those areas where `EnglishMinimalStemFilter` is invocated, so this is not a proper solution. If you want to be able to search with stems when not using a wildcard, have two different fields and use `copyFields` to index the same content into both. Use one (that does not have stemming, etc. - only tokenization and lowercasing, and possibly lowercase the query before sending it to Solr yourself) for wildcard searches and one for regular searches (with stemming, etc.)